# C# If Statement with value from field in Table

Tags: c#, database, if-statement, visual-studio-lightswitch

**How do I write this statement to get a value back from the database or table and validate that if the Value = Yes it will return the "Result =10" part. The field is called "ApprovedStatus" the value will either be "No" or "Yes".**

Visual Studio Tells me this: "The name 'Yes' does not exist in the current context"

```
If (ApprovedStatus.Equals = Yes)
{
result = 10;
}

else
{
result = 1;
}
```

Comment: Isn't `Equals` a method? Also, you are using one equal sign.

Answer (score 5):

Try `if (ApprovedStatus == "Yes")` if it's a string, or `if (ApprovedStatus)` if it's a bool.

Answer (score 1):

If ApprovedStatus is of type bool, do:

```
if (ApprovedStatus)
```

Should it be string, do **NOT** do this

```
if(ApprovedStatus == "Yes")
```

because this will equal **false** if ApprovedStatus = "yes"

Instead use

```
if(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(ApprovedStatus,"Yes"))
    result = 10;
else
   result = 1;
```

**Note that if you do**

```
if (ApprovedStatus.ToString().ToUpper().Equals("YES"))
```

or

```
if( ApprovedStatus.Equals("whatever",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

**it will throw a null reference exception if ApprovedStatus is null.**
...which is possible to likely if the value comes from a database.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ApprovedStatus.Equals("Yes"))  <-- Case Sensitive
{

}
```

or

```
if (ApprovedStatus.ToString().ToUpper() == "YES")
{

}
```

Comment: (1) `Equals` is a method, not a property.  (2) `==` is the equality operator, not `=`.  (3) You don't compare the result of `Equals()` to the value you want to compare, you pass the value to `Equals()`.

Comment: Yeah I know - I was in a real hurry on this one.  My apologies.  On a side note - one extension method I use quite frequently is string.EqualsCI("value") where EqualsCI() does a case insensitive comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess given the limited info available... (Assuming ApprovedStatus is a String)

```
if(ApprovedStatus == "Yes") 
{ 
   result = 10; 
} 

else 
{ 
   result = 1; 
}
```

or

```
if(ApprovedStatus.Equals("Yes")) 
{ 
   result = 10; 
} 

else 
{ 
   result = 1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use String.Compare -- it's more efficient.

```
if(String.Compare(ApprovedStatus, "Yes", true)==0){
 result = 10;
} else {
 result = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Boolean values in C# are `true` and `false`. You should consult a basic C# tutorial, but your check has probably to look like this:

```
if (ApprovedStatus)
{
   result = 10;
}
else
{
   result = 1;
}
```

It can be written shorter as:

```
result = ApprovedStatus ? 10 : 1;
```